# Error al crear un workspace en Apex 20.2 en Oracle 12 C alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Tags: oracle, apex

Adjunto imágenes para facilitar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el usuario no se haya creado por restricciones en la base de datos.

Valide creando el usuario en la base de datos, si es exitoso, cree el espacio de trabajo seleccionando dicho usuario creado.